# Как обработать флажок checkbox в сервлете?

Tags: java, servlet, checkbox

Пишу веб-сервис. Использую java,servlet,jetty,freemarker,hibernate,mysql (на всякий случай перечислил всё).

В html файлике есть табличка с несколькими полями (tr), в первом столбце которых находится checkbox.

Идея следующая:

1. Ставлю флажок для какого-то поля
2. Мой сервлет видит, что checkbox как-то изменился (либо добавился новый класс, либо какае-та аттрибутка data-* добавилась, хз что)
3. Начинаю оперировать с данными из выбранной строки

Подскажите, как это сделать?

Если что в процессе общения с Вами либо код добавлю, либо что-то еще необходимое сообщу.
В голову не приходит решение что можно сделать, поэтому пока буду параллельно еще искать в гуугл.

Comment: у чекбокса есть атрибут `value` попробуйте читать этот параметр в сервлете из `HttpServletRequest req`

Comment: Найдите и почитаете литературку про формы html

Answer (score 1):

Сервлет не сможет сам отследить изменения на форме, вам надо будет отправить форму.

Пример:

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/myservlet" method="post">
  <input type="radio" name="radio1" />
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

В самом сервлете по адресу, `/myservlet` останется только принять переменную

```
request.getParameter("radio1")
```

**[UPD]**
Можно обернуть таблицу в форму, выйдет нечто подобное:

```
<form>
  <table>
   <tr>
     <td>
      <input type="text" name="someText">
     </td>
     <td>
      <input type="radio" name="istextChaned">
     </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Да, так действительно получается получить информацию о том, что чекбокс выбран.

Но возникает следующая проблема:
Такой чекбокс должен находиться в форме.
А у меня такой чекбокс находится в таблице, а форма отправляющая пост-запрос никак не контачит с таблицей.